# How to hide text field item based on true or false cases in Oracle Apex

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a set of text Field items in Oracle Apex:

1. Order Number
2. Revision Number

When we open the report, revision should be hidden.

Only when the user enters unique order number (non-duplicate order numbers), revision number should be visible.

If he enters duplicate order number, revision number should be hidden.

Comment: Do you need to do it without of page reload (only in browser)?

Comment: How reliable must the uniqueness check be? What if two people happen to enter the same order number at around the same time?

Comment: Hi, if i am not wrong, this action should happen during the run time of the report. Right now we are not much concerned about 2 people entering order number at the same time.Thank you :)

Comment: It's been a while...do you still need the answer to this question?

Answer (score 1):

A simple (though not bullet-proof) solution is to create a Dynamic Action on the Order Number item that, when Changed, issues a query on the database to check if the order number already exists; if found, it hides the Revision Number item, otherwise it shows it.

You would want to ensure there is a suitable index on the order number column on the database so that the query returns as fast as possible.

If two people are in the screen at the same time, and enter the same order number, the query will not see the order number so this method is not guaranteed to always work perfectly.